# Jenkins deleting batch file before it's completed

Tags: jenkins

I'm running Jenkins on a Server 2012 VM, and I'm noticing that some of my projects are being marked as incomplete when they are successful. I am getting the error 'The batch file cannot be found.' The problem, from what I can tell, is that the batch file Jenkins is creating to run my project is being deleted before it's completed. I'm migrating from a windows 7 box where this issue doesn't happen.

I've been able to watch as the batch file is created in `C:\Users\164016\AppData\Local\Temp\` and then it's deleted before the batch file completes. I'm even able to open the batch file before it's deleted.

I've tried placing the Call command at the beginning of the command, but that doesn't resolve the issue.

The LaunchPad.exe command is a custom made script designed to return exit codes from Excel vba macros.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Here is the log:

```
Building remotely on (164016) Remote Computer in workspace C:\TEMP\Jenkins Slave\workspace\Weekly Claim Edit WQ Age
[Weekly Claim Edit WQ Age] $ cmd /c call C:\Users\164016\AppData\Local\Temp\hudson3188220465265190989.bat

C:\TEMP\Jenkins Slave\workspace\Weekly Claim Edit WQ Age>"O:\Analytics Team\Tasks\Automation Components\Ryan\C#\Launch Pad\LaunchPad\LaunchPad\bin\Debug\LaunchPad.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Quest Software\Toad for Data Analysts 2.7\Toad.exe" -batch=true "O:\Analytics Team\Tasks\Automation Components\Cindy\TAS\Claim_Edit_WQ_Age.tas" "O:\Analytics Team\Tasks\Claim Edit WQ Age\Claim_Edit_WQ_Age.xlsm"  

LaunchPad Start Time: 10.7.2014 9:49:10 AM
Time before Stopping Programs: 60 min

Program: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Quest Software\Toad for Data Analysts 2.7\Toad.exe"
Arguments: "-batch=true" "O:\Analytics Team\Tasks\Automation Components\Cindy\TAS\Claim_Edit_WQ_Age.tas" 
vba File: "O:\Analytics Team\Tasks\Claim Edit WQ Age\Claim_Edit_WQ_Age.xlsm"
vba Exit File: O:\Analytics Team\Tasks\Claim Edit WQ Age\Claim_Edit_WQ_Age.txt


Report Completed: 10/7/2014 9:50:28 AM 164016  O:\Reports\EPIC\Epic Claim Edit WQ\20141007 Claim Edit WQ Age.xlsx

Exiting LaunchPad: No Errors Detected: 0
The batch file cannot be found.
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 5):

I had a very similar problem. I was running a job in Jenkins that was calling a specialized internal program and causing the "batch file not found" error. It turns out there was a `del %TEMP%\*.* /q` command in one of the batch files being run. This was deleting all of the Jenkins temporary batch files in the middle of the job and causing the error.

The simple solution is to simply relocate the Jenkins temp folder. This can be done by adding a command line option to your Jenkins startup script. My startup script looks like: `java -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\!!My_user_name!!\Desktop\Jenkins_Temp -jar jenkins.war`

The important part I added was the `-Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\!!My_user_name!!\Desktop\Jenkins_Temp` option (Removed my user name for privacy reasons.) This fixed the problem. Don't forget to replace my path with with a valid path name for your system.

The command line option should be added to both the master and slave startup scripts for proper operation.

Comment: I faced the very same problem.

    dir('C:\\dev\\abc\def')
    {
        bat 'some command'
    }

would let Jenkins create its bat file in c:\dev\abc\def (real name simplified). So far no problem, except that  abc\def is a branch of a git repo and the command executed git clean -x -d -f, which also cleaned up that Jenkins tempfile!

Answer (score 0):

You've got something else at play here...

When you configure **Execute Windows batch command** build step, it creates a temporary batch file that Jenkins then executes.

The execution of the temporary batch file starts at:
`[Weekly Claim Edit WQ Age] $ cmd /c call C:\Users\164016\AppData\Local\Temp\hudson3188220465265190989.bat`
and it finishes at:
`Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure`

The temporary batch file `hudson3188220465265190989.bat` would be deleted **after** that last line.

Your error `The batch file cannot be found.` happens **before** that line. So, it's not the Jenkins temporary batch file that cannot be found, but something else.

Unless you provide the content of your **Execute Windows batch command**, it's difficult to guess what else could be the problem.

Comment: Execute Windows batch command: "LaunchPad.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Quest Software\Toad for Data Analysts 2.7\Toad.exe" -batch=true "O:\Analytics Team\Tasks\Automation Components\TAS\Claim_Edit_WQ_Age.tas" "O:\Analytics Team\Tasks\Claim Edit WQ Age\Claim_Edit_WQ_Age.xlsm"

Comment: From debugging LaunchPad - the deletion of the batch file appears to happen after this line executes: process = Process.Start(processInfo);

Comment: The odd part is that the temporary batch file appears to be being deleted before the last line is completed.

Comment: For debugging purposes, you can put `pause` (job won't finish until you kill it) or `ping -n 50 127.0.0.1` (will ping loopback 50 times before closing) into the Execute Windows batch command, just to give a delay before Jenkins deletes the temporary `.bat` file.

Comment: If I add the pause command at the beginning, it works. If I add it at the end, it never runs because the batch file is deleted.

Comment: The only other time I've seen something like this happen is when one batch A calls another batch B, and that other batch B is executing an `exit` command without `/b`. The result is that it kills the whole calling chain, without returning to batch A. I don't see any secondary batches in your example, but I don't know what `.tas` format is either. Does that `.tas` file contain batch commands in any form?

Comment: It might... It's Dell's Toad (SQL) automated process. However, it is working correctly on the Windows 7 machine.

Comment: Run it from within a batch file on that Windows 7 machine, and see if the behavior is same. Remember, "Execute Windows Batch Command" is just a temporary batch file that Jenkins creates and executes

Comment: Also, try putting `START "" /WAIT "LaunchPad.exe"` with proper paths and all. The double `""` are required.

Comment: If I run it from a self made batch file on Windows 7, everything runs fine. Same if I run it from Jenkins.   When I run it from a self made batch file on Server 2012, Toad crashes. This is something I wasn't seeing under Jenkins.

Comment: I corrected that issue, now it runs correctly from a self made batch file on Server 2012. However, the issue with the Jenkins temp batch file being deleted remains the same.

Comment: Tried START "" /WAIT - I saw a cmd prompt open, and the output location changed, but the same issue persisted.

Comment: Well, I am out of ideas

Comment: It looks like the problem lies with Toad and Jenkins on Server 2012. If I strip everything else out of the equation except Toad, I still get the deleted batch file issue.

Comment: Thank you for all of your suggestions.

Comment: I am able to confirm using Sysinternal's ProcMon, Toad is deleting the Jenkins temporary batch file before it's completed. I'll updated if I can find a way to limit Toad from doing this.

Comment: I was able to have me c# script locate and lock the temporary batch file to prevent Toad from deleting it. The lock is released when the script closes, and everything appears to be running properly.

Comment: Glad you sorted this out